# CakePHP can't make app/tmp writable on windows 7

Tags: cakephp, windows-7, wamp

I am getting `unable to write` errors using cakephp.  I see lots of solutions for unix (e.g. chmod) but I can't find anything that works for Windows.

How can i set app/tmp to be web writable?

Cake sits on the C: drive, could that be relevant?

Comment: "_Cake sits on the C: drive, could that be relevant?_" You could simply test it by moving it onto another drive...

Comment: Windows doesn't have chmod, but it does still have folder permissions. http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/155448-changing-folder-permissions.html

Comment: Sarah- I tried to add permissions manually to no avail